# Why am I seeing so many duplicate images in my thumnails folders?

Tags: files, media

Why am I seeing tons of duplicate images in my sites/default/files/data_export_import/styles/test_thumbnails

There are so many in there, like 4 gigs, I'm going over quota, how can I clear this and not delete the images that are being used? Site has 256 pages...

How can I clean this mess up?

[image]

Comment: run cron, `/admin/config/system/cron`

Comment: Are these images coming from a feed import?

Comment: No, client simply uploaded duplicate images to multiple content items...! How can I run a cron to assign same images to diff content items?